# Create html table from reading json file locally or from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

Have a Nodejs script that queries from postgres and writes the data to a json file, queryResult.json.

In a new html file, I am able to create html tables dynamically when I hard code the json data to a variable. However, I am unsure how to proceed in terms reading in the json file from local storage or if I would need to use an external JS library to help.
I did try just now by adding an ajax call to get the file from local storage/folder, but I am getting a cors related error. I suppose I will need to host this file. Are there any other ways to test this locally? Maybe a local webserver like wamp or something is what I am thinking?

html code https://pastebin.com/Wir6zfUm

```
<body onload="CreateTableFromJSON()">
  <p id="showData"></p>
</body>
<script src="queryResult.json" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  function CreateTableFromJSON() {

    var results = [
    {
      "unique_id": "0555163995",
      "group": "Robomonkey",
      "status": "Assigned",
      "last_responder": "batman",
      "last_response_date": "2021-04-02T06:43:24.000Z"
    }
  ]

  // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
  var col = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    for (var key in results[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

  var table = document.createElement("table");
  // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell.innerHTML = results[i][col[j]];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So a few things first off..

1. why would you write the JSON response to a file?
2. When you say local storage are you referring to actual localStorage or just stored locally? ( kind of important to know :D )

Based on the question title, I'm assuming you are using Node, so with that there is not really a good reason to write the JSON response from PG to a file, you would just return the query response in the response ( unless, for some reason you need to write it to a file but this is not really a great way of doing that )

What you want to do is use a templating engine ( as an example I'm using EJS )

The flow then would be to use EJS and loop over your PG response like so

```
   res.render('path/to/ejs/view', {
                            items: [pg response],
                            })
```

pg response would be the variable return by the pg query.

Then on your ejs page you would do something like

```
<% for ( i in pg-response){ %>
<tr><td> <%-pg-response[i].item %></td></tr>
<%}%>
```

Now this is not to say you have to use EJS or any templating engine for that matter, you could just expose the JSON from and API and do an XHR request as well but a templating engine should work well.

On the flip side, you will always get a cors error when trying to run locally without a web-server. You don't need WAMP if you are using NODE as it is the webserver and should run off localhost:port allowing for you to make an XHR request to the endpoint.